Save np.ndarray frame from opencv with using Gstreamer as video recorder
Hello, guys.
So i have problem with python3 api of gstreamer. I can't write correctly video in format .mov (i add frames np.ndarray in gstreamer) with using gstreamer. So in constructor i send filename like hostname-date.mov .But all videos has zero bytes size. I think problem may be in method: def release(self) -> None: or in def __init_pipeline(self).
class CustomVideoWriter:
    """ Class that modifies a video stream    
    """

    def __init__(self, filename: str, fps = 22) -> None:
        """
        __init__ 
            Constructor class CustomVideoWriter
        Parameters
        ----------
        filename : str
            Name of the currently being written file

        fps : int
            FPS of the video stream
        """
        # 
        self.desired_fps = fps

        if FLAG_USED_GSTREAMER:
            self.filename = filename
            self.pipeline = None
            self.width = None
            self.height = None
            self.appsrc = None
  

    def __init_pipeline(self):

        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

        # Create elements
        self.appsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("appsrc", "source")
        videoconvert1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "videoconvert1")
        videoconvert2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "videoconvert2")
        x264enc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("x264enc", "x264enc")
        avimux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("avimux", "avimux")
        filesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "filesink")

        if not self.appsrc or not videoconvert1 or not videoconvert2 or not x264enc or not avimux or not filesink:
            print("Not all elements could be created")
            return

        # Set properties
        self.appsrc.set_property("is-live", True)
        self.appsrc.set_property("format", Gst.Format.TIME)

        filesink.set_property("location", self.filename)

        # Add elements to the pipeline
        self.pipeline.add(self.appsrc)
        self.pipeline.add(videoconvert1)
        self.pipeline.add(videoconvert2)
        self.pipeline.add(x264enc)
        self.pipeline.add(avimux)
        self.pipeline.add(filesink)

        # Link elements
        self.appsrc.link(videoconvert1)
        videoconvert1.link(videoconvert2)
        videoconvert2.link(x264enc)
        x264enc.link(avimux)
        avimux.link(filesink)

        # Set pipeline state to PLAYING
        ret = self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
            print("Unable to set the pipeline to the PLAYING state")

    def write(self, frame: np.ndarray) -> None:
        """
        write 

        The function of initializing the pipe gstreamer and writing the frame to a file

        Parameters
        ----------
        frame : np.ndarray
            Frame for record
        """
        if FLAG_USED_GSTREAMER:
            if self.pipeline is None:
                self.width, self.height = frame.shape[:2]
                self.__init_pipeline()
            data = frame.tobytes()
            buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(data), None)
            # Push buffer into appsrc
            ret = self.appsrc.emit("push-buffer", buf)
            if ret != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
                print("Failed to push buffer to appsrc")
            else:
                print("Done writing frame to file")

    def release(self) -> None:
        """
        release 

        The function of freeing memory from the video stream for recording
        """
        if FLAG_USED_GSTREAMER:
            if self.pipeline:
                self.appsrc.emit("end-of-stream")
                bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
                self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
                self.pipeline = None

If you have any idea how to solved/ rewrite please write here :D
Thank you for you help!

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

well, no ) i understand what i send in method. Yes, it is np.ndarray . Something wrong with closing/save flow gstreamer or maybe wrong with __init_pipeline in parameters.

maybe you know what this program should do - but it seems it doesn't do it. And using print() you may see if it has correct values in variables. OR you have to learn how to use real debuger

BTW: to see what is the problem we would have to run it and probably use print() to debug it - but we can't run it. So we can only suggest to debug it (ie. with print()) :(

In release(), after you get the bus, you may try to wait for EOS or ERROR message such as msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, Gst.MessageType.EOS | Gst.MessageType.ERROR). If the received msg is of type EOS, the video would be correctly saved.
